# Get last 3 thursday dates based on the date we input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to get the last three Thursday dates based on the date which I gave. I got it right if i insert a Tuesdays date but does not work for a Friday date. What i did was:

```
select dt from (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by(d.dt)) as rn from  
(SELECT Top 4 CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(Month, -1, '5/29/2012')+number,101) as dt 
FROM master..spt_values WHERE TYPE ='p' AND 
DATEDIFF(d,DATEADD(Month, -1, '5/29/2012'),'5/29/2012') >= number 
AND DATENAME(w,DATEADD(Month, -1, '5/29/2012')+number) = 'Thursday') as d ) 
as nw where nw.rn>1
```

and the output I get is 5/10/2012, 5/17/2012, 5/24/2012.

But when I change the date to 5/18/2012 the output i get is

04/26/2012, 05/03/2012, 05/10/2012

But it should be 05/3, 05/10, 05/17.....What is wrong or is there any other method to do this?

Comment: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `DATEADD(Month, -1,` with `DATEADD(Week, -4,` and it starts working for Fridays and Saturdays.

Explanation: If you subtract a Month it usually substracts 30 or 31 days, which adds an extra Thursday if the start date is a Friday, Saturday or (in the 31 days case a Sunday). After that the Top 4 cuts the last Thursday in the list.

Edit, to just select three values:

```
select * from (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by(d.dt)) as rn from   
(
   SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(Week, -3, '5/25/2012')+number,101) as dt  
   FROM master..spt_values WHERE TYPE ='p' 
   AND DATEDIFF(d,DATEADD(Week, -3, '5/25/2012'), DATEADD(Day,-1,'5/25/2012')) >= number  
   AND DATENAME(w,DATEADD(Week, -3, '5/25/2012') + number) = 'Thursday') as d
)
as nw
```

Comment: Thanks a ton it works ...Can i get three dates directly ??as of now am getting four values and taking three ignoring the first record

Comment: @karthi I just added a solution that does this. The -1 day is needed because you get one too many if you enter a Thursday otherwise.